# Как создать видеохостинг

Tags: flash, php, видео, хостинг

У меня есть несколько видеофайлов на своем хостинге. Хочу создать из них видеохостинг как на http://youtube.com. Как это можно будет осуществить?

Comment: видео личное? или пиратское?

И второе а зачем велосипед если есть ютуб?

Видеохостинг - предоставление любому пользователю в сети залить видео и далее распространять ссылку на видео либо сделать закрытым видео для личного просмотра.

Comment: Хочу узнать как устроен ютуб. Видео есть личное, есть пиратское.

Comment: Война и Мир, в двух словах, быстро)))))

Comment: за пиратское видео тебя быстро прикроют :)

Comment: Определись, что тебе нужно. Разместить видеофайлы на сайте, чтобы пользователи могли их посмотреть - это одно. Это легко.
А видеохостинг - это сервис, на котором пользователи добавляют своё видео. Тут посложнее, да и ресурсов нужно больше.

Comment: Денег много? Если много и ты готов платить по 1К а то и более в месяц за ресурсы, просто за ресурсы серверов, то я готов вписаться в проект за отдельную плату. если же  у тебя нет денег и ты хочешь сделать что-то похожее на ютуб - то бросай сразу эту тему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ставишь движок видео-сайта и все.

Вот, какие движки я встречал:

- [PHPmotion](http://phpmotion.com/)  - **Клон ютьюба.** В рунете встречаются руссифицированные версии. Движок бесплатный.
- [vShare Video Sharing](http://vshare.in/)  цена 10$. Говорят хороший движок.
- [ClipShare](http://www.clip-share.com/) от 99$. Русской версии вроде как нет.

Еще можно джумлу поставить и расширение на добавление видео.